# Type parameter inference in pattern matching

Tags: scala

I am trying to create some kind of heterogeneous map and came up with the following code

```
sealed trait Key[V]
case object LongKey extends Key[Long]

case class KeyValue[V](key: Key[V], value: V)

object KeyValue {
  def values(key: Key[Long], kvs: List[KeyValue[_]]): List[Long] =
    kvs.collect {
      case KeyValue(LongKey, v) ⇒ v: Long // this compiles
      case KeyValue(`key`, v)   ⇒ v: Long // this doesn't
    }
}
```

As `Key` is sealed and invariant I would have expected the 2 lines to be interchangeable.
Why does the second case not compile?

```
...: type mismatch;
  found   : _$1 where type _$1
  required: Long
       case KeyValue(`key`, v) ⇒ v: Long
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question. I initially thought this "should" work, but consider:

```
val kv: KeyValue[_] = KeyValue[String](null, "a")
val key: Key[Long] = null
kv match {
  case KeyValue(`key`, v) => v // returns String, not Long!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the way type system guaranty that your function is correct.

When you make your function signature,

```
def values(key: Key[Long], kvs: List[KeyValue[_]]): List[Long]
```

`KeyValue[_]` means `KeyValue[Z] forSome { type Z }`

When compiler does type inference, there is no way to make sure that the return would be `List[Long]`, without constraining the case match to only `KeyValue(LongKey, v)`.

If you need a generic function to collect the values, you could rewrite it as below.

```
def values[V](key: Key[V], kvs: List[KeyValue[V]]): List[V] =
  kvs.collect {
    case KeyValue(keyType, v) ⇒ v
  }
```

On the other hand, if you want constrain them to only Long types, you need to change the function signature to,

```
def values(key: Key[Long], kvs: List[KeyValue[Long]]): List[Long]
```

That would allow you to pattern match on `case KeyValue(key, v)`. Because compiler could verify that only Long type is to be expected.

Comment: Indeed the final version would be `values[V]` but I simplified to show that the compiler is able to infer the correct type for `v` when I match against the case object. Also I really want to mix the different types of KeyValues otherwise I could just stick with a `Map[K, V]` :). Rephrasing my question: in ```case KeyValue(`key`, v)``` what are the possible types of `v` given that `key` is a `Key[Long]`?